# remove numeric characters from filenames with ruby

Tags: ruby, filenames

Good morning everyone. I need to write a Ruby script to remove numeric characters from file names in a folder. It works, but unfortunately some files are deleted, because once the numeric characters are removed they would have the same name, or they would be empty. I tried to insert a condition to avoid it, but nothing is renamed anymore. Can you help me? This is the code:

```
require 'fileutils'
folder = ARGV[0]
Dir.chdir(folder)
Dir.glob("*.*") do |file|
  new_name = file.gsub(/[0-9]/, "")
  FileUtils.mv(file, new_name) if !file.empty? && !File.exist?(file)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Rather than `file.gsub(/[0-9]/, "")` you could write `file.delete "0-9"`, which arguably reads better. Picky? I can't help it. Converting only some file names seems odd. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have to run another script (in Python language) that renames the files with the sequence 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 and I noticed that the numeric characters are not read as numbers but as letters, and then the files are not numbered in the correct sequence

Comment: Suppose the files were named `'a12'`, `'ab23'` and `'ab245'`. Then consider renaming them `'1.1   a12'`, `'1.2  ab23'` and `'1.3 ab245'`. By adding spaces to make all file names the same length they are lexicographically ordered by the prefixes. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean to write this:

```
!new_name.empty? && !File.exist?(new_name)
```

Instead of this:

```
!file.empty? && !File.exist?(file)
```

> nothing is renamed anymore

... Because the script was saying "don't rename any files that exist"

Comment: While the `unless` notation is likely unfamiliar to someone new to Ruby, in more idiomatic form this would be `FileUtils.mv(...) unless new_name.empty? || File.exist?(new_name)`

Comment: @tadman I would actually opt for making the script more verbose -- Those are two different error conditions which could probably do with being handled more explicitly!

Comment: 1. If the filename contains all-numbers, is that an *error*? It's a bit of an odd script to "delete all numbers, unless the filename only contains numbers". Maybe it could at least log a warning, or something?

Comment: Absolutely! Two guard conditions that can emit proper errors instead of just doing nothing and telling nobody about the problems.

Comment: 2. If the edited filename has a collision, should the script silently fail to rename it? Maybe it could use a different name, or maybe it's an error, or - again - maybe it could at least log a warning.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the existing answer, you should check and report back if certain conditions are met. By printing to `STDERR` you can silence those errors if you choose, or have them printed.

```
require 'fileutils'
folder = ARGV[0]
Dir.chdir(folder)
Dir.glob("*.*") do |file|
  new_name = file.gsub(/[0-9]/, "")

  if new_name.empty?
    STDERR.puts "ERR: #{file}: new file name would be empty."
  elsif File.exist?(new_name)
    STDERR.puts "ERR: #{file}: moving to #{new_name} would overwrite existing file."
  else
    FileUtils.mv(file, new_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: This way it works perfectly. I'm not an expert on Ruby as you may have understood, and sometimes I make trivial mistakes! Thank you all for your help. Last request: what if I also want to eliminate the blanks in addition to the numbers?

Comment: Add whitespaces to the regular expression character class you're replacing with `""`. `/[0-9\s]/`